# The view 'GetMetaDataDetails' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a page lets say `Edit.cshtml` in that page is a dropdownlist of item to updated. the loading of that page has no problem, the problem comes when I select an item on the dropdownlist and execute an ajax call.

```
$('#dDL').kendoDropDownList({
        optionLabel: "Select",
        dataTextField: "Value",
        dataValueField: "Id",
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: '@Url.Action("GetItems", "BulkEdit")',
            }
        },
        change: function (e) {
           //this is where i call the '@Url.Action("GetMetaDataDetails", "BulkEdit")'
            var test = getMetaDataDetails();

            popupwindow.data("kendoWindow").open();
            popupwindow.kendoWindow({
                width: "600px",
                title: "Mapping",
                visible: false,
                //modal: true,
                animation: {
                    close: {
                        effects: "fade:out"
                    }
                },
                actions: [
                    "Pin",
                    "Minimize",
                    "Maximize",
                    "Close"
                ],
            }).data("kendoWindow").center().open();
        }
    });
```

it goes through the controller with no issue, but it throws error if I return a view. Why?

this is my ajax call:

```
function getMetaDataDetails() {
        return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetMetaDataDetails", "BulkEdit")',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({ itemTypeID: itemtypeID.toString() }),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
                var checks = data;

            },
            error: function (data) {
                debugger;
                var check = data;
                alert(result);
            }
        });
    }
```

and this is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public virtual ActionResult GetMetaDataDetails(int itemTypeID)
        {
            var importProperties = GetImportColumnProperties(GetModel(itemTypeID));

            var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(importProperties, Formatting.Indented,
                           new JsonSerializerSettings
                           {
                               ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                           });

            ViewData["MetaDataModel"] = importProperties;

            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

This is the pop-up window that should be populated after executing the `getMetaDataDetails()`, `itemMetaData` should have the values return by `getMetaDataDetails()`

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
            .Name("itemwindow")
            .Title("Item Mapping")
            //.Modal(true)
            .Content(@<text>
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Table Column</th>
                            <th>Excel Column</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    @foreach (var props in itemMetadata.GetType().GetProperties())
                    {
                        var label = props.GetCustomAttribute<CanBulkUpdateAttribute>().CanBulkUpdate;
                        if (label == true)
                        {
                            var disp = props.GetCustomAttributes<DisplayPropertyName>();
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="col-sm-3">
                                        <label>
                                            @disp.First().DisplayName
                                        </label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="col-sm-3">
                                        <select kendoDropDownList name="" id="ddlitem_@props.Name" style="width :250px;"></select><br>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        }
                    }
                </table>
                <button id="uploadAll" onclick="updatetable()" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>

            </text>)
            //.Width(420)
            .Height(440)
            .Visible(false)
    )
```

I need to use the return of GetMetadataDetails as model for my `"popupwindow"`
Hope you can help me.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: The view 'GetMetaDataDetails' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations

Comment: The `return View(importProperties)` is the problem source - it returns a view but you're not specifying a view name to render with (by default MVC treats same view name as controller name if no view name argument used when returning a view).

Comment: How should I fix this? I'm just new in MVC. What I did is
return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); but since this is the second call, how can i bind it to my pop-up window?

Comment: You say "What I did is return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); " but that isn't what you did - `return View(importProperties);`. So the main question: What exactly do you expect to be returned from that action? ie what does your javascript expect to be in the response. Also why do you serialize something to result and then never use it?

Comment: I updated my question to show `Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)` 
What exactly do you expect to be returned from that action? 
 - I want to return this model `MetadataColumns`
Also why do you serialize something to result and then never use it?
 - I haven't figured out how to process the value of `Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)`

Comment: this is my `MetadataColumns`
`public class MetadataColumns
        {
            public PropertyInfo Property { get; set; }
            public string DisplayName { get; set; }
            public string PropertyName { get; set; }
            public bool CanBulkUpdate { get; set; }
        }`

Comment: so what is the current error? The view 'GetMetaDataDetails' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations -- that cannot be the error now as you've replaced with return Json(...)